# How to solve Exception It is unsafe to run Dusk in production in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk

I upgrated my project from laravel 5.4 to laravel 5.5 ,

I dont have any problem in local env but in server i get this exception ,

I searched a lot and i know this issue may be duplicated but no solutions solved my problem!

How can i not registering dusk when environment is production?

i wrote this code in AppServiceProvider.php :

```
public function register()
{
    // Dusk, if env is appropriate
    if ($this->app->environment('local', 'testing')) {
        $this->app->register(DuskServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

but it seems not working.
can anyone help?

EDITED :
my composer.json file:

```
 "require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "1.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0.3",
    "symfony/css-selector": "4.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "4.0.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.4",
    "laravel/dusk": "^2.0"
  },
```

The Exception is :

```
Exception
It is unsafe to run Dusk in production.
```

Comment: Can you please add the exception to your question?

Comment: dusk package in composer.json require-dev ?

Comment: Yes it's in require-dev. but i dont want to use composer install --no-dev @Chaoyenpo

Comment: added to the question. @CUGreen

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Laravel 5.5, packages are automatically discovered and loaded so you will probably need to tell it not to load dusk.

One way is to add this to your composer.json

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "laravel/dusk"
        ]
    }
},
```

Also, you can add it to your dev dependencies and when you deploy in production, use:

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Taylor wrote an article about it [here](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/package-auto-discovery-in-laravel-5-5-ea9e3ab20518).

Comment: In this way works but I cannot manage to test with Dusk on Travis CI.
Because TravisCI install all the composer packages every time, so if dusk is in "dont-discover" it cannot find it.

Answer (score 6):

Look, it does not work because it is configured to work on `local` and `testing` environment. 
I guess that you need to add 'production' (if your production is called 'production in your `.env` file environment:

AppServiceProvider

```
public function register()
{
    // Dusk, if env is appropriate
    if ($this->app->environment('local', 'testing', 'production')) {
        $this->app->register(DuskServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

When installing to production server I just needed to use the `--no-dev` flag

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Good luck!

Comment: look now, i improved answer

Comment: Thank you but is there a way to not running that ? no other solutions?

Comment: i made resaerch - is only one solution.

Comment: Which register method is this? There are a lot of register() method in Laravel, please assist me in finding this one.

Comment: Do it in AppServiceProvider

Answer (score 1):

**If you're experiencing this problem while in a developing environment** and accidentally landed here due to the title, you should check that your `.env` file is set up for development. It should contain the line

`APP_ENV=local`

Here is an example of how the `.env` file could look: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example

And here is the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration

---

Also, in `composer.json`, `laravel/dusk` should be listed under `require-dev` and not `require`.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether file which named `.env` contained in the source folder and setup Database user name and password and other settings.

I had the same problem because I have set all the things but forgot to change the `.env.example` to `.env`