# getting errors while installing a crud project create by adminpanel laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I have created a CRUD project in "quickadminpanel.com".
the downloaded and extracted inside a folder and created a connection to my database inside ".env" file. 
In my terminal, I made a path to my project folder and then when I write "composer install" 
it starts fine but at the end, in terminal I get this errors:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In DuskServiceProvider.php line 43:

  It is unsafe to run Dusk in production.  


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

but even when I ingore this error and write "php artisan migrate --seed"

I get this error :

```
In DuskServiceProvider.php line 43:

  It is unsafe to run Dusk in production.
```

I really need to get this project done guys pleas any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve Exception It is unsafe to run Dusk in production in laravel 5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622200/how-to-solve-exception-it-is-unsafe-to-run-dusk-in-production-in-laravel-5-5)

Comment: thanks alot @LexLustor.

Comment: but even after manipulating complser.json file I still get this error:

Comment: In DuskServiceProvider.php line 43:
                                           
  It is unsafe to run Dusk in production.